# Xamarin IOS - rotating picture (UIImage) for 180 degrees around center point

Tags: ios, xamarin, rotation, uiimage

Im trying to rotate UIImage by 180 degrees around its center point using CGAffineTransform but it is not working as i want :/

Code:

```
    UIImage RotateImage(UIImage imageIn) {
    int kMaxResolution = 2048;

    CGImage imgRef = imageIn.CGImage;
    float width = imgRef.Width;
    float height = imgRef.Height;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity ();
    RectangleF bounds = new RectangleF( 0, 0, width, height );

    if ( width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution )
    {
        float ratio = width/height;

        if (ratio > 1)
        {
            bounds.Width  = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.Height = bounds.Width / ratio;
        }
        else
        {
            bounds.Height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.Width  = bounds.Height * ratio;
        }
    }

    float scaleRatio = bounds.Width / width;
    SizeF imageSize = new SizeF( width, height);
    float boundHeight;

    //This piece of code should make this UImage upside down            
    transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation (imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);
    transform = CGAffineTransform.Rotate(transform, (float)Math.PI);
    //=============

    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(bounds.Size);

    CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

    context.ScaleCTM(scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    context.TranslateCTM(0, -height);
    context.ConcatCTM(transform);
    context.DrawImage (new RectangleF (0, 0, width, height), imgRef);

    UIImage imageCopy = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

    return imageCopy;
}
```

Image is scaled after this, but its not upside down. Why?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me, so I c/p'd into a project and it rotates and scales the output fine. If you are doing this more then once, you should look at 
CIAffineTransform and CILanczosScaleTransform as it would be much faster.

Comment: Can you provide some screenShot? I used your code and it works fine.